# Sounds on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: sound

I recently installed ubuntu 18.04 and would like to know how to get the sounds like the ones that were on 16,04. I get sound from my external speakers but no startup sound I tried system settings, and activities manager without any luck. So far I really like 18.04 but it seems to me the help system could be improved.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little off topic.

There are plenty of sites with sound effects.

http://www.grsites.com/archive/sounds/category/21/?offset=0

I created a directory called My_Sounds where I collect my sounds.

Answer (score 0):

You could play around with the alert sounds if that helps:

1. Click on the Sound icon at the top bar (Top right corner) Then click on the tool icon at the bottom of the popup windows that will show.
2. Click on the sound option
3. Enable the annoying alert sound system.

[image]

If you wish to add more options or change the existing ones you can always go to

```
/usr/share/sounds/gnome/default/alerts
```

which holds the sound files that show in the list.

[image]

The decision for the current sound system was talked about in https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/new-system-sounds-in-18-04/1557/8 along with a couple of options of adding a full sound theme, so maybe this could help you install a sound system in your particular case (am more of a silent person, got enough sound from my mouse that every time I click my neighbor can hear it).